# Are there any laws in the US to prevent a predatory guardianship?

Tags: guardianship

When a guardian becomes custodian over a vulnerable old person and put them in assisting facilities they can decide about the selling of assets of those people on behalf of their wards; but it is always open to abuse.

Is there any laws preventing such an abuse in the US?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Such laws are ubiquitous. An example is Washington's RCW [11.130.325](https://app.leg.wa.gov/RCW/default.aspx?cite=11.130.325). The nutshell version is:

> (1) A guardian for an adult is a fiduciary and owes the highest duty
> of good faith and care to the person under a guardianship. The
> guardian shall not substitute his or her moral or religious values,
> opinions, or philosophical beliefs for those of the person under a
> guardianship. Except as otherwise limited by the court, a guardian for
> an adult shall make decisions regarding the support, care, education,
> health, and welfare of the adult subject to guardianship to the extent
> necessitated by the adult's limitations.
>
> (2) A guardian for an adult shall promote the self-determination of
> the adult and, to the extent reasonably feasible, encourage the adult
> to participate in decisions, act on the adult's own behalf, and
> develop or regain the capacity to manage the adult's personal affairs.

Then, [under §350](https://app.leg.wa.gov/RCW/default.aspx?cite=11.130.350),

> (1) The court may remove a guardian for an adult for failure to
> perform the guardian's duties or for other good cause and appoint a
> successor guardian to assume the duties of guardian

Being "predatory" i.e. acting in one's own interest is good cause.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it is a cure, not a prevention: "*The court may remove...*"

Comment: @SnackExchange well, yes, any authority you give to a person or group might be abused. You could make the system more robust by adding additional controls (a committee instead of a single person, or supervision of each decision by a court) but those can fail too, and you have to weight in the additional costs that those measures imply.

Comment: I mean, there are laws against murder, rape and theft, but even those do not mean that murder, rape or theft no longer happen...